# Why am I getting undefined on console when I am passing props in my component file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, destructuring, react-functional-component

I tried logging it onto console and I was getting undefined wherever I have used props,hence nothing is coming onto my browser wherever I have used props.The tags after it are working totally fine as expected and no errors are being shown.

This is the code where I used props at

```js
const AnotherHeading = (props) => {
    const a = props.text;

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{console.log(props.name)}</h1>
            <div>{a}</div>
            <p>{console.log("object")}</p>
            <main>This is main</main>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </>
    );
};

const AnotherHeading2 = () => (
    <>
        <div>
            <h1>This is Another Heading 2</h1>
        </div>
    </>
);
const AnotherHeading3 = () => (
    
    <>
    <div>
        <h1>This is Another Heading 3</h1>
    </div>
    </>
)
const AnotherHeading4 = () => (
    
    <>
    <div>
        <h1>This is Another Heading 4</h1>
    </div>
    </>
)



export default AnotherHeading;
export {AnotherHeading2,AnotherHeading3,AnotherHeading4};
```

This is the code from where I am passing props from

```js
import { AnotherHeading2, AnotherHeading3 } from "./components/AnotherHeading";
//import AnotherHeading from "./components/AnotherHeading";
import RandomTag from "./components/AnotherHeading";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <AnotherHeading2 name="Prajjawal" text="Nice One" />
            <AnotherHeading3 />
            <h1>This is a heading</h1>
            <RandomTag />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I looked at syntax and it seems fine to me, I am unable to understand why this is happening, I also tried destructuring but ended up having the same results again and again.

Comment: Hi! Nothing in the code you've shown actually uses `AnotherHeading`, so we can't help you understand why `console.log(props.name)` in that component doesn't log what you expect.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: You don't pass any prop to `<RandomTag />`, 
`<RandomTag name="some name" text="some text" />` should work

Comment: @zb22 Thank you so much, I have been stuck on this simple error from so long.